# use RXJS to unsubscribe when a Subject emits specific value

Tags: rxjs

I think I should leverage RXJS for a particular use case. The use case is that I have a subscription that I want to live until a certain value is emitted from a Subject somewhere else.

Eg:

```
// The sub to unsub when a certain <value> is emitted from a Subject elsewhere.
this.someObservable.subscribe(() => ...)


// Somewhere in the code far, far away, this should kill the subscription(s) that cares about <value>
this.kill.next(<value>)
```

My go to approach to handle this is caching the subscriptions and then unsubscribing when `this.kill.next(<value>)` with the relevant `<value>` is called. Though, that is the imperative approach and feels like it can be done better via `takeWhile` or some other such technique. Perhaps I might need to merge `someObservable` with `kill` Subject ?

How can I leverage RXJS to handle this?

Comment: All of the options seem doable. Go with what seems the most straightforward to you and your team.

Comment: Sounds like just `takeUntil(this.kill.pipe(map(/* ... */))`

Comment: @martin what goes inside `map`? something like: `map((val) => val === <valueOfInterest>)`?

Comment: Ups, I mean't `filter()` not `map()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

takeUntil is the operator you want

```
this.someObservable.pipe(
  takeUntil(this.kill.pipe(filter(val => val === killValue)))
).subscribe(() => ...)
```

Once the kill observable emits the killValue it will pass the filter and emit to the takeUntil which unsubscribes the stream.

```js
const { timer, fromEvent, Subject } = rxjs;

const { takeUntil, filter } = rxjs.operators;

const kill$ = new Subject();

kill$.subscribe(val => {
  console.log(val);
});

timer(500, 500).pipe(
  takeUntil(kill$.pipe(filter(val => val === 'kill')))
).subscribe(val => {
  console.log(val);
});

document.getElementById('rnd').addEventListener('click', () => {
  kill$.next(Math.random());
});

document.getElementById('kill').addEventListener('click', () => {
  kill$.next('kill');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.6.2/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<button id="rnd">Emit random</button>
<button id="kill">Emit kill</button>
```

Comment: It just occurred to me that the two values being compared are unknown until emitted. So, using the top part of the answer, the `killValue` will be unknown and emitted by `kill$`, and `someObservable` (seen in the top part of your answer) emits a value that must be compared against the `killValue`. I'm not sure how to get access to the `killValue` within `this.kill.pipe`. Also assuming `val` is the value emitted from `someObservable`, correct?